# How to change system "Hide All" keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I've looked through the list of all keyboard shortcuts in `Settings app -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts` but I can't find the one for "Hide all (other) windows".

The default is **CMD-OPT-H** but it conflicts with another application. I'm also looking for a way to change it's shortcut, as an alternative. But in the meantime, does anyone know how/where to change this default shortcut?

I've googled it, looked in the OS X system help, and searched through the Settings app, but I can't seem to find it. Thanks!

*Note: 
I'm using OS X Yosemite (10.10.4)*

Answer (score 2):

You have to add it manually in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That worked, except that the `CMD-OPTION-H` command also still "Hides Others." Is there anything else I can do to disable that? I've never used that command intentionally, so I doubt it will cause me any problems to disable it.

Comment: That's strange, once changed `CMD-OPTION-H` does nothing for me. Check this out for more info: http://superuser.com/questions/284140/is-it-possible-to-change-or-override-the-default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-finder

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I replaced the shortcut as described above, with something totally different, but still the combination CMD-OPTION-H (which is not shown in the Finder menu as the shortcut for "Hide others") is hiding others. It's extremely frustrating. There really should be a way to stop this from happening. It's so frustrating since there's no "game mode" to disable all other app shortcuts while in a specific app. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command in the terminal then restart. This way works for me. Now you can reassign the Cmd-Option-H to another thing else.

```
defaults write "Apple Global Domain" NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Hide Others" nil
```